# attention_mask is missing in the returned dict from tokenizer.encode_plus

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have a codebase which was working fine but today when I was trying to run, I observed that `tokenizer.encode_plus` stopped returning `attention_mask`. Is it removed in the latest release? Or, do I need to do something else?

The following piece of code was working for me.

```
encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                truncated_query,
                span_doc_tokens,
                max_length=max_seq_length,
                return_overflowing_tokens=True,
                pad_to_max_length=True,
                stride=max_seq_length - doc_stride - len(truncated_query) - sequence_pair_added_tokens,
                truncation_strategy="only_second",
                return_token_type_ids=True,
                return_attention_mask=True
            )
```

But now, I get only `dict_keys(['input_ids', 'token_type_ids'])` from encode_plus. Also, I realized that the returned `input_ids` are not padded to `max_length`.

Comment: Can you add which version of `transformers`/`tokenizers` you are currently running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I updated the tokenizers API to 0.7.0 which is the latest version. However, the latest version of the transformers API works with tokenizers 0.5.2 version. After rollbacking to 0.5.2, the issue disappeared. With `pip show`, I see the following.

```
Name: transformers
Version: 2.8.0
Summary: State-of-the-art Natural Language Processing for TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

```
Name: tokenizers
Version: 0.5.2
Summary: Fast and Customizable Tokenizers
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers
```